# Install pdo_sqlsrv has error PHP Fatal error: Unsupported processor architecture

Tags: php

This project's web application is using the framework Phalcon (PHP 8.1), connecting to DB MySQL (8.0) and DB sql server.  Regarding the current environment structure, there are 2 EC2 Instances, 2 NAT Instances, 1 RDS MySQL, 1 Sql server

The project has successfully connected RDS MySQL.  Connecting to sql server is reporting an error:

> PHP Fatal error: Unsupported processor architecture.

I have successfully installed the extension `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` (5.11.1) but still get the above error, please help.

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo
sudo yum update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql mssql-tools unixODBC-devel re2c gcc-c++ gcc
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Config php.ini:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Please help me fix.

Comment: Check your system architecture with `uname -m`, check you so file with `file yourExtension.so`.   Then see if they are match.

Comment: @LF-DevJourney It is aarch64 , do you know if the pdo_sqlsrv extension is compatible with aarch64? Please introduce me

Comment: Above is two command, one is check your system, the other is check your so file. Can you paste here?

Comment: @LF-DevJourney I've posted it below

Comment: @LF-DevJourney https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863845/23284140

Comment: It seems the microsoft sql server driver not support your system architecture.

Comment: @LF-DevJourney Thank you, perhaps there is no other way